# How to add LinkedResources to Flex-Config.xml

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to figure out how to add linked resources to flex-config.xml. In my .properties file it looks like

```
<linkedResources>
        <link>
            <name>[source path] src</name>
            <type>2</type>
            <location>/Users/gfrank/repos/project/project_tes/src</location>
        </link>
    </linkedResources>
```

and I want to add this to my flex-config.xml since we are using a make file to build the swfs and what not. I can't seem to figure out how to add this. Does anyone know? I tried using various tags like  and what not but nothing seems to work and when I compile the project it can't find the source of the files in the above location.

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `source-path` element in flex-config.xml:

```
  <source-path>
     <path-element>/Users/gfrank/repos/project/project_tes/src</path-element>
  </source-path>
```

You could also specify multiple source-paths in your makefile; in my Ant build scripts, I use:

```
<mxmlc ...>
    <source-path path-element="@{path1}" />
    <source-path path-element="@{path2}" />
</mxmlc>
```

Comment: Didn't work, I had added the source path tag as suggested and when I try to import from the above path com.greg.manager for the PlayerManager class, which lives in project/src/com/greg/manager/PlayerManager.as it says it can't find the source for PlayerManager.as, flash builder finds it fine but when I try to make the project with the makefile it says the error.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `<compiler>` block.  Also see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67670-7ff2.html

Comment: We tried that in the compiler tag and didn't work :(, not sure why, in our library i shows up as a testSrc folder but when it makes the project it seems it can find that source path, I will double check that it is in the right place when my colleague gets back.

Comment: I am still getting 48 Error: The definition of base class gregManager was not found. which is in the above path at src/com/greg/manager

Answer (score 0):

The answer Brian gave seems to be the correct one but apparently still didn't work, but when we moved the -Source-path to the compiler arguments under project/properties/Flex Library Compiler it worked fine. Very strange.